# Can typefaces belong to an IP?

Tags: intellectual-property

Under most countries typefaces are not protected by copyright, only computer fonts. But are typefaces protected by other types of IP (trademark, patent, etc.)?

Comment: The title is awkwardly phrased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variations in typefaces are not functional so they can’t be the subject of utility patents. The US also has design patents for ornamental aspects of an item. The item can be an icon on a screen but I don’t think you could get a whole alphabet design patented.

Trademark is the primary protection of typefaces. You could use the shapes of Helvetica but don’t call it Helvetica or anything misleading close.